# jPlayer maintaining playback after button click

Tags: c#, jquery, asp.net, visual-studio-2012, jplayer

I have an asp button:

```
<asp:ImageButton CssClass="button" ID="ImageButtonLogin" runat="server" Text="Login" OnClick="ImageButtonLogin_Click" ImageUrl="upload.jpg" />
```

CodeBehind jus creates a new div, adds it to a PlaceHolder and then make some asp controls visible.

I also have jPlayer implemented. The problem is, when I click on above button (or any other button/link), music stops and then I cannot resume playback (like after pausing), it seems that jPlayer unloads the song.

It seems like button click reloads entire site or something, so:

1. is there a way to force buttons not to reload entire page?, or
2. can i place my jPlayer in some place, where it will be 'safe' and the other part of my site will not affect it?

Thank You for answers, it's my first asp.net website and I appreciate all the help You can provide :)

Comment: That's correct behavior of the button click it's called a `PostBack` you may want to read up on what a `PostBack` is and what happens when it is fired [MSDN Page.IsPostBack Property](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.ui.page.ispostback.aspx)

Comment: Ok, so is there a way to force playback through them PostBacks? If not, how can I separate my player from the site so that it is not reloaded with it?

Comment: you can do a check for if(IsPostBack){ } hard to really tell without seeing your exact code.. if it's not too much code paste your code in your original question section not in the comments section